# MS SQL and PHP echo floating point number

Tags: php, sql-server

There is probably a simple solution to this, but, I can't figure it out.

I have coordinates stored in an MS SQL Server 2016 database and I'm trying to print them to my `PHP` page for a map. However, I am just getting a blank value or 0 depending on how I try to do this.

Does anyone know how to echo a floating point number from MS SQL using `PHP`?

Code sample:

```
<?php
    $count=1;
    $sel_query="Select * from engagements WHERE x IS NOT NULL ORDER BY 'id' desc;";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($con,$sel_query);
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
        L.marker([<?php echo(float) $row["x"]; ?>, <?php echo(float) $row["y"]; ?>]).addTo(mymap)
         .bindPopup("<b><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></b><br /><b>Category:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $row["category"]; ?><br /><b>Importance:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $row["Importance"]; ?><br /><b>Group:</b>&nbsp;<?php echo $row["group"]; ?>");
<?php $count++; } ?>
```

I am using:

> - PHP version 7.2.10
> - WAMP Server 3.1.4 32-bit
> - MS SQL Server 2016

Comment: Another issue: Remove the quotes around id in your query.

Comment: Ya, sorry. I'm updating a bunch of pages from MySQL. Either way, it will still work with quotes. Thanks though

Comment: No it will not work with quotes. It makes the `order by` useless.

Comment: Use decimal(9,6) for latitudes and longitudes. Take a look at this [article](https://sqlsouth.wordpress.com/2013/11/12/storing-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates/).

Comment: What are the data types of your 'x' and 'y' columns - decimal(x, y), float? And can you post some sample values for these columns? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, just got it working about 15 minutes ago. The echo(float) worked, the x field was capitalized and it took me several hours to realize it :-( TGIF.